# PowerShell - if statement condition that produces multiple results

Tags: powershell

Please consider this silly example:

```
if (1..3) { "true" }
```

The above produces the output **true**.

My question: How does the if statement handle a case like this where multiple values are output by the conditional? Is the "true" output the result of the "3" (the last case)? Or is some other logic at work? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. I think this is a valid question pointing to something that is not well documented in powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above produces the output true, as expected.

Why do you expect it to output "true"?

> How does the if statement handle a case like this where multiple values are output by the conditional?

The conditional does not "output" any values. It always evaluates to "true" or "false". The question remaining is, why does it evaluate to true (or false).

The code

```
   if (1..3) { "true" }
```

is equal to

```
   if (@(1,2,3)) { "true" }
```

is equal to

```
   $array = @(1,2,3)
   if ($array) { "true" }
```

behaves as

```
   if ($array.Length -gt 0) { "true" }
```

So not individual elements are tested, but rather if the array contains any elements.

For example, the following will *not* print "true":

```
   if (@()) { "true" }
```

**Update** If the array contains only one value, it *looks* (I coudn't find any normative documentation on that), as if the array is treated as a scalar value using the one element inside.

So

```
   if (@(0)) 
   if (@(0.0)) 
   if (@(1)) 
   if (@(-1)) 
   if (,$null)) 
   if (,"false"))
```

is treated as

```
   if (0)  --> false
   if (0.0)  --> false
   if (1)  --> true
   if (-1)  --> true
   if ($null)  --> false
   if ("false") --> true
```

Comment: Not true... `@(0).length = 1` but try `if (@(0)) { "true" }` and see what you get.

Comment: Well not completely false also. It looks like a corner case. See my update.

Comment: +1 Thank you Christian.K for your explanation.  It seems @(0) is treates as a special case (or corner case as you put it).

Comment: What does the comma prefix do in the last two case?

Comment: > `Why do you expect it to output "true"?` You are right, that was not a valid assumption. I have edited the question and removed it. – Sabuncu 6 mins ago

Comment: It is just a different way of creating an array. See [here](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html).

Answer (score 4):

The observed behavior is explained (to some extent) in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx). Basically, if an expression evaluates to 0 it's interpreted as false, otherwise as true. Examples:

```
0      => False
1      => True
"0"    => True (because it's a string of length 1)
""     => False (because it's a string of length 0)
@()    => False
@(0)   => False (this one's a little surprising)
@(0,1) => True
@("0") => True
```

Comment: You say: "if an expression evaluates to 0" -> how is the "evaluation" accomplished?

Comment: @Sabuncu I'm not familiar with PowerShell's inner workings, so I can't explain how exactly PowerShell evaluates particular expressions. That is a question you need to ask the developers.

Answer (score 1):

1..3 results in an array with 3 items

```
PS> (1..3).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS> (1..3).Length
3
```

If there is at least one item in the array the if considers it true

```
PS> if (@()) { "true" } else { "false" }
false

PS> if (@(1)) { "true" } else { "false" }
true

PS> if (@(1,2)) { "true" } else { "false" }
true
```

Comment: Not true... @(0).length = 1 but try if (@(0)) { "true" } and see what you get.