# Adding string to variable powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to create a powershell script that will append a character to my variable only if the variable is not null.  For instance a user fills out a form,  or spreadsheet cell in my case and it has data I want to append a | to that variable so when I call that variable in my script it will display | contents of variable.  This is what I have and it does not seem to be working.

```
 if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($field6))
  {$field6 = $field6}
 else 
  {$field6 = "| $field6" }

  }
echo $field6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
if ($field6 -ne $null) { $field6 = "| $field6" }
```

Comment: You can even skip the explicit null check: `if ($field6) { $field6 = "| $field6" }`

Comment: @mousio That may yield undesired results, because there are [other values than `$null`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17085458/1630171) that will make `if ($field6)` evaluate to `$false`.